# Передача сообщения в onReceive

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alarm-manager

Необходимо в методе onReceive использовать сообщение. Как в метод передать сообщение?

P.S. Установка в AlarmManager происходит в классе MainActivity, метод onReceive находится в классе AlarmReceiver.

P.S.S. Чтобы было понятнее, в методе onReceive() появляется Notification, в теле которого мне необходимо указать, о чём пользователь хотел получить напоминание. Это напоминание мне необходимо передать в метод onReceive().

Comment: Какое сообщение? А каком `onReceive()` - штатный экстрасенс опять ушел в отпуск - вот скотина :)

Comment: После установки будильника в AlarmManager (AlarmManager.set()) происходит вызов метода onReceive(). Это происходит в классе MainActivity. Метод onReceive() находится в классе AlarmManager, унаследованный от BroadcastReceiver. Мне необходимо передать "сообщение" в этот метод при установке будильника.